# Only show one form for nested_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, limit, nested-attributes

I would like to show only one nested form for the one-to-many relationship between user and appointments. A user can only create one appointment and the form should only show fields for one appointment regardless of how many appointments he has.

I've tried the :limit option

```
class User
  has_many :appointments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments, limit: 1
end
```

I also tried limiting the number of appointments built in the controller

```
class UsersController
  def edit
    @user = current_user
    1.times { @appointment = @user.appointments.build }
  end
end
```

I always end up with a nested form for each appointment the user has plus an additional nested form. I know I could change the relationship to one-to-one but this is for legacy code and its likely that the relationship will be one-to-many in the future.

Is there a way that I can only show one nested form regardless of how many appointments a user has?